Ubuntu doesn't boot and i get this error
installed it yesterday.
logged out, login didn't work, i rebooted, then this happened.
it's the latest version (24.04)
i'm quite new to linux so if i made a really silly mistake linux pros wouldn't make, don't be mad at me :/
edit: different image because it changed after a few reboots
commands i used today:
nano .custom-start.sh 
bash .custom-start.sh 
nano .profile 
bash-l
bash -l
./CurseForge-1.251.0-17831.AppImage 
sudo apt install libfuse
sudo apt install libfuse.so.2
sudo apt install fuse
./CurseForge-1.251.0-17831.AppImage 
sudo ./CurseForge-1.251.0-17831.AppImage 
sudo apt install nautilus
nautilus



By any chance, did you install any packages or did you make any changes to the system, e.g. installing new python version?

@ArchismanPanigrahi yeah i reinstalled flatpack and nautilus bc they broke.
edit: i already checked; my hard drive and ram are NOT faulty

Can you try (CTRL + C, CTRL + X or q) to skip the process. It looks like a audio driver issue and has to be reported to ubuntu distributor by sudo systemctl enable apport-autoreport.service
It happens when your pc onboard hardware has a compatibility issue.
If you stack, can you plug out any jak or audio cards from the computer so that it will not detect any audio hardware at that step.
Lastly you can try to plug headphones or speaker to see that error is happening again.
Let me know the results so that I can help you better.
